# How do I left-align entries in a matrix with \begin{matrix}?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, matrices

I'd like to left align the -1 entry in the following matrix so that the 1s line up. Is there a way to get matrices to ignore signs in that way?

```
\begin{matrix}
    1 & 1  \\
    1 & -1 \\
\end{matrix}
```

Using `\flushright{-1}` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: mathtools allows you to l/r align entries in matrices. In your example, putting an \hfill before the upper 1 should also work.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

I know that this is an old question, but to whoever stumbles upon this from a Google search (like I just did) another very elegant solution for this is using the starred matrix environments of [`mathtools`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools?lang=en):

- `\begin{matrix*} [〈col〉] 〈contents〉 \end{matrix*}`: simple matrix,
- `\begin{pmatrix*}[〈col〉] 〈contents〉 \end{pmatrix*}`: matrix surrounded by matching parenthesis,
- `\begin{bmatrix*}[〈col〉] 〈contents〉 \end{bmatrix*}`: matrix surrounded by matching square brackets,
- `\begin{Bmatrix*}[〈col〉] 〈contents〉 \end{Bmatrix*}`: matrix surrounded by matching curly brackets (braces),
- `\begin{vmatrix*}[〈col〉] 〈contents〉 \end{vmatrix*}`: matrix surrounded by matching vertical lines (like for determinant),
- `\begin{Vmatrix*}[〈col〉] 〈contents〉 \end{Vmatrix*}`: matrix surrounded by matching double vertical lines.

The `<col>` optional argument specifies the column alignment, and should be `c`, `l` or `r` for centered (default), left-aligned and right-aligned, respectively. Consider the following example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
  -1 & 3 \\
  2 & -4
\end{pmatrix*}
\]

\[
\begin{Bmatrix*}[l]
  1.001 &\hdots & 3  \\
  2.3 & \hdots & 4.2
\end{Bmatrix*}
\]

\[
\begin{Vmatrix*}[c]
  1 &  3  \\
  \tfrac{1}{2} & 4.2
\end{Vmatrix*}
\]

\end{document}
```

which yields

[image: Example]

The `mathtools` package is an extension of `amsmath` that fixes various bugs/deficiencies and adds some useful tools (like the starred matrix environments).

Comment: This is definitely the way to do it!

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the most elegant solution. Updated the accepted answer.

Comment: @Will I put a bounty to award this answer to make it more visible since it _is_ the way to go. And now here you are, making it the accepted one :)

Comment: I just improved the examples and the answer a bit, since there is this new bounty in place.

Comment: `mathtools` has the same `*`ed variants of the family of `smallmatrix` environments.

Comment: Great answer. I added an answer for the case in which the numbers have different number of digits.

Answer (score 38):

A quick way to do this is by adding *phantom* characters:

```
\begin{matrix}
    1 & \phantom{-}1  \\
    1 & -1 \\
\end{matrix}
```

[image]

Although for simple arrays like this it's probably simpler just to use a standard array environment

```
\begin{array}{rr}
    1 & 1  \\
    1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
```

for the same result. Note that if you need control over alignment, then array is the preferred way to typeset matrices (you can simply wrap in `\left( ... \right)` etc. for brackets and lines).

Comment: You're welcome! For extra information on mathematics environments, the [documentation of the `amsmath` package](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) is an excellent resource.

Comment: qubyte: your comment has a broken link

Comment: It’s not too surprising (the comment is from 2012). A quick search revealed an up to date URL. http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.pdf

Answer (score 27):

If you using LaTeX2e out of the box, you can use the `array` environment, which is similar to a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{rr}
    1 &  1  \\
    1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution:

```
\begin{matrix}
    1 & \hfill 1  \\
    1 & -1 \\
\end{matrix}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the environments of `nicematrix`, you have an option `r` for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[r]
1 & -1 \\
1 & 1
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

The question of @Dimas is fine. The `\begin{pmatrix*}[r]`, however, does not work well when the numbers have a different number of digits. Let me add this answer, which defines a new column type [C]. It requires the `tabularx` package. Note: This answer is based on another answer from StackExchange (I could not identify the link).

Here is the code and the output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeatletter
\def\zz\ignorespaces{\@ifnextchar-{}{\phantom{-}}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\zz}{c}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1234\\
-2 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
1 & 1234\\
-2 & 2
\end{bmatrix*}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix*}[C]
1 & 1234\\
-2 & 2
\end{bmatrix*}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

With the `spalign` package of the **October 5, 2016**, using the command `\spalignmat` option right `r` it is possible to have easily the alignment of the signs of the matrix's elements.
There is also the option `c` (center) and `l` (left).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{spalign}
\begin{document}
\[ \spalignmat[r]{-5 -1 +2; -1 -5 +7; +1 -6 -3} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]