# Align values in bmatrix

Tags: align, matrices

Is it possible to renew the `bmatrix` environment to have alignment?

I would like the following vectors to show aligned:

```
\begin{bmatrix}
 -0.505 & \\
 -0.141 & \\
 0.144 & \\
 0.839 & \\
\end{bmatrix}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45001/how-do-i-left-align-entries-in-a-matrix-with-beginmatrix

Answer (score 8):

**Example with matrix environment. Work also for bmatrix**

*Taken from [here](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/matrix-align-left-right/). Article by Stefan Kottwitz.*

This code produces unaligned numbers:

```
\[
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 &  2 &  1 \\
    0 & -2 & -3 \\
    0 & 3 &  -2
  \end{pmatrix}
\]
```

[image]

However, the environment can be renewed to support alignment:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][c]{\hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols #1}}
\makeatother
```

Now it is possible to do:

```
\[
  \begin{pmatrix}[r]
    1 &  2 &  1 \\
    0 & -2 & -3 \\
    0 & 3 &  -2
  \end{pmatrix}
\]
```

which outputs:

[image]

Comment: which is already build into the `bmatrix*` environment, which is available through the `mathtools` package

Comment: What I like about Alan's answer is that it allows me to choose the default (by replacing [c] with [r] in the definition, say).