# How to align in smallmatrix?

Tags: align, matrices

I want to right-align everything, but it does not seem to work inline:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{a4wide, fancyhdr}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

Matrix $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}[rr] 2 & -2\\ -1 & 4 \\ 0 & 6\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ 
or this $\vec{a}=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}[r] x \\ -3 \\ 5\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ ...text...

\end{document}
```

Any thoughts? [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156928/137734) does not help...

Comment: Please add a complete MWE.

Comment: Are you even using `mathtools`, if you are you are not asking it to be right aligned. As mentioned, provide a full minimal exmaple not just a sniplet

Comment: @epR8GaYuh See my edit...

Comment: The answer you refer to mentions `mathtools` explictly, you are not using it.... simple as that

Comment: plus `a4wide` is not a recommended package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are referring to the right answer, just use it correctly

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

Matrix $A=\begin{psmallmatrix*}[r] 2 & -2\\ -1 & 4 \\ 0 & 6\end{psmallmatrix*}$ 
or this $\vec{a}=\begin{psmallmatrix*}[r] x \\ -3 \\ 5\end{psmallmatrix*}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I ignore package `a4wide`?

Comment: @Christoph yes, learn to use the geometry package to set proper margins (or what ever the interface of the class you are using offers, article has none, though do remember the `a4paper` class option, the default is US letter)

Answer (score 1):

Using `\hfill` is a much easier solution, for example:

```
\left\{ \begin{smallmatrix} 
x^3+y^3+z^3 \hfill & = & 1 \\ 
x^2+y^2+z^2 \hfill & = & 0 \\ 
x^3+x^2+y+z \hfill & = & -1 
\end{smallmatrix} \right.
```

Comment: What do you mean? Where should I use `\hfill`?

Comment: Example:\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}
x^3+y^3+z^3\hfill&=&1\\
x^2+y^2+z^2\hfill&=&0\\
x^3+x^2+y+z\hfill&=&-1
\end{smallmatrix}\right. Of course I needed it to display equations

Comment: Please add that example directly into the answer, comments are easily missed. Fleshing out the example to a full MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and adding a picture of the output are a nice touch (though by no means a must). I would say that in its current form without further explanation about where the `\hfill` ought to go, the answer needs some work.