# Alignment of matrix entries using physics package

Tags: alignment, mathtools, physics

I'm looking for a way to achieve the same output (regarding the alignment of matrix entries) using the `physics` package - or simply a conformation that will work only with `mathtools` ([like here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45001/how-do-i-left-align-entries-in-a-matrix-with-beginmatrix)). Either way, thx in advance.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{physics}

% workaround found by adding an optional argument to the original code
% (note the xparse package was already loaded with physics)
\DeclareDocumentCommand\pmqty{O{r} m}{\begin{pmatrix*}[#1]#2\end{pmatrix*}} % adjusted
%       VS
% \DeclareDocumentCommand\pmqty{m}{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}  % original
\DeclareDocumentCommand\pmqtyOld{m}{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}} % for comparison

\begin{document}
    $\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    -1 & 3 \\
    2 & -4
    \end{pmatrix*}$

    $\pmqtyOld{
        -1 & 3 \\
        2 & -4
    }$

    $\pmqty{
        -1 & 3 \\
        2 & -4
    }$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify your question ?  what ouput is expected ? Is the use of the vastly debated physics package really needed ?

Comment: I want to achieve the output on the left side, but atm i have that one on the right side. PS: vastly debated, so is there already an equally alternative?

Comment: as a Physicist, i never use this package. Vastlly debated means , e.g.
Alternatives to the physics package (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471532/ and references in it). What is the problem with he mathtools solution ?

Comment: Whare abouit 
`newcommand\Pmqty[1]{\begin{pmatrix*}[r] #1 \end{pmatrix*}}

\[ \Pmqty{-1 & 3 \\     2 & -4} \]` ??

Comment: Hmm... to be honest, i do not want to change the package on the last mile of writing - however, i cannot ignore the ugliness in specific equations ^^#      PS: in your last remark i found the way to go for me, thx (and for the future i will consider to switch to other packages ^_~)