# Matrices side by side with a column break in-between

Tags: amsmath, matrices

My question is to get the following output using LaTeX. I'm using **article** class with **amsmath** package. I can of course get the matrices but not the form as appeared in the image. Any help in getting this done is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: `matrix*` from `mathtools` is recommended; see [How do I left-align entries in a matrix with `\begin{matrix}`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45001) for all you ever wanted to know about this.  But really, you should have included code to show us what you've already tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  E_1&=
  \begin{bNiceArray}{rrr}[first-row,last-col]
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\mathclap{\textcolor{magenta}{\text{Elementary Matrix}}}}\\
        0 & 1 & 0 &\textcolor{magenta}{R_1\leftrightarrow R_2}\\
        1 & 0 & 0 & \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & \\
  \end{bNiceArray}
  &
  E_1^{-1}&=
  \begin{bNiceArray}{rrr}[first-row,last-col]
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\mathclap{\textcolor{magenta}{\text{Inverse Matrix}}}}\\
        0 & 1 & 0 &\textcolor{magenta}{R_1\leftrightarrow R_2}\\
        1 & 0 & 0 & \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & \\
  \end{bNiceArray}\\
  E_2&=
  \begin{bNiceArray}{rrr}[last-col]
        1 & 0 & 0 &\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & \\
        -2 & 0 & 1&
        \textcolor{magenta}{R_2+(-2)R_1\to R_3} \\
  \end{bNiceArray} 
  &
  E_2^{-1}&=
  \begin{bNiceArray}{rrr}[last-col]
        1 & 0 & 0 &\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & \\
        2 & 0 & 1 & \textcolor{magenta}{R_2+(2)R_1\to R_3} \\
 \end{bNiceArray}  \\
  E_3&=
  \begin{bNiceArray}{rrr}[last-col]
        1 & 0 & 0 &\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & \\
        0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} &
        \textcolor{magenta}{(\tfrac{1}{2})R_3\to R_3} \\
  \end{bNiceArray} 
  &
  E_3^{-1}&=
  \begin{bNiceArray}{rrr}[last-col]
        1 & 0 & 0 &\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & \\
        0 & 0 & 2 & \textcolor{magenta}{(2)R_3\to R_3} 
  \end{bNiceArray} \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is `blkarray`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  E_1&=
  \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
  \textcolor{magenta}{\text{Elementary Matrix}}\\
  \begin{blockarray}{[rrr]l}
        \bigstrut[t]0 & 1 & 0 &\textcolor{magenta}{R_1\leftrightarrow R_2}\\
        1 & 0 & 0 & \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & \\
  \end{blockarray} 
  \end{array}
  &
  E_1^{-1}&=
  \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
  \textcolor{magenta}{\text{Inverse Matrix}}\\
  \begin{blockarray}{[rrr]l}
        \bigstrut[t]0 & 1 & 0 &\textcolor{magenta}{R_1\leftrightarrow R_2}\\
        1 & 0 & 0 & \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & \\
  \end{blockarray}
  \end{array} \\
  E_2&=
  \begin{blockarray}[t]{[rrr]l}
        1 & 0 & 0 \bigstrut[t]&\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & \\
        -2 & 0 & 1&
        \textcolor{magenta}{R_2+(-2)R_1\to R_3} 
  \end{blockarray} 
  &
  E_2^{-1}&=
  \begin{blockarray}[t]{[rrr]l}
        \bigstrut[t]1 & 0 & 0 &\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & \\
        2 & 0 & 1 & \textcolor{magenta}{R_2+(2)R_1\to R_3} \\
  \end{blockarray} \\
  E_3&=
  \begin{blockarray}[t]{[rrr]l}
        \bigstrut[t]1 & 0 & 0 &\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & \\
        0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} &
        \textcolor{magenta}{(\tfrac{1}{2})R_3\to R_3} \\
  \end{blockarray} 
  &
  E_3^{-1}&=
  \begin{blockarray}[t]{[rrr]l}
        \bigstrut[t]1 & 0 & 0 &\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & \\
        0 & 0 & 2 & \textcolor{magenta}{(2)R_3\to R_3} 
  \end{blockarray} \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is beautiful ! Much appreciated.

Comment: @Quantas You're welcome!

Comment: For the solution with `nicematrix` it's possible to put `\NiceMatrixOptions{code-for-first-row = \color{magenta},code-for-last-col = \color{magenta}}` and avoid putting `\textcolor{magenta}` each time.

Comment: @F.Pantigny Thanks for the heads up. Yes, that's a good suggestion. (I had the `blkarray` first and then copied the code from this answer to the other one.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, when I ran your first code it gives me an error: ! Package nicematrix Error: Your version of LaTeX (especially expl3) is too
(nicematrix) old. You can go on but you will probably have
(nicematrix) other errors if you use the functionalities of
(nicematrix) nicematrix.
Type <return> to continue.

Could you please let me know how to get rid of this. Thanks.

Comment: @Quantas I think that the only reasonable way to get rid of this is to update your TeX installation. The author of `nicematrix`, who is the author of the third comment, made substantial efforts to further improve their nice package, so it is best to use the most recent version. (And I would not even know how to install an older version on my machine.)

Comment: I did install the new version 5.0.4 but still the problem previals. Anyway, I'll check. Glad to know that @F.Pantigny, is the author of the code.

Comment: @Quantas I think that `nicematrix` complains that your `expl3` code/package is too old. Unless you have already done so, you may want to update the complete TeX installation. On my TeXLive 2020 installation this runs without problems.

Comment: @Quantas: If you really want an older version of `nicematrix`, send me an email: fpantigny@wanadoo.fr